# How to format a large text containing special Characters and breaklines?

Tags: formatting, characters, code

I have this rather long text which is the output of a several console inputs. I'd like to have the text as it is as of right now.

Here a link to the raw text since I didn't want to include it in this post: 
http://pastebin.com/9SZaw1ZP

I tried replacing the special characters with the correspondending escape characters. But it still causes a lot of issues. I am fairly new to LaTeX too.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You want to have a look at the `verbatim` environment or else to the `listings` package.